# Python new multiple list with no duplicates. All new lists aligns with first new list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Current Output:

```
['Jay', 'Boon', 'Sue', 'Tim', 'Lia', 'John', 'Abe']
[]
[]
```

Ideal Output:

```
['Jay', 'Boon', 'Sue', 'Tim', 'Lia', 'John', 'Abe']
[20,     40,    ,26,    28,     21,    91,     25]
[...]
```

````
NamesFromForum = ['Jay','Boon','Jay','Sue','Tim','Lia','Lia','John','John','Abe']
AgesFromForum = [20,40,30,26,28,21,18,91,10,25]
LocFromForum = ['BA','CA','NM','CO','AL','NY','TX','NV','MN','SO']

NameNoDup = []
ageAlignName = []
LocAlignName =[]

for x in NamesFromForum:
    if x not in NameNoDup:
        NameNoDup.append(x)

for y in AgesFromForum:
    for x in NamesFromForum:
        if x not in NameNoDup:
            AgesFromForum.append(y)

for z in LocFromForum:
    for x in NamesFromForum:
        if x not in NameNoDup:
            LocFromForum.append(z)


print(NameNoDup)
print(ageAlignName)
print(LocAlignName)```
````

Comment: I am not sure what you intend to do, but you are not append to ageAlignName and to LocAlignName, so they are empty when printed out. I think you need to use classes to represent the data, as names, ages and locations appear to be related.

Comment: You added all names to "NameNoDup" in the first for-loop so later checks of "x not in NameNoDup" will always be false.

Comment: So NamesFromForum list has duplicate names. I wanted to remove the duplicate names into a new list called NamesNoDup.

The AgesForum list also aligns with the namesfromforum list in the same order so, the first Jay is age 20, so i want to remove the ages that both the new list will be the same amount of items

Comment: Why do you use separate lists for each value, instead of a list of tuples, dictionaries, or objects? It's always easier if you keep related data together. Using separate lists like this was necessary 40 years ago in languages like Fortran and BASIC that didn't have aggregate data structures. I'm guessing this was long before you were born.

Comment: @Barmar I am new to python and doing a web scrapping project. There are duplicate titles with other attributes in the row containing the title, like date and hyperlink.  so to understand how to make this work for that, i made a simple concept above and i can learn and apply it to the more convoluted code i have made

Answer (score 0):

Best to use a control set to ensure that you don't add duplicate names rather than scanning the list every time (it's faster). Then use zip to align the lists. Something like this:

```
NamesFromForum = ['Jay','Boon','Jay','Sue','Tim','Lia','Lia','John','John','Abe']
AgesFromForum = [20,40,30,26,28,21,18,91,10,25]
LocFromForum = ['BA','CA','NM','CO','AL','NY','TX','NV','MN','SO']

NameNoDup = []
ageAlignName = []
LocAlignName =[]

nameSet = set()

for name, age, loc in zip(NamesFromForum, AgesFromForum, LocFromForum):
    if name not in nameSet:
        NameNoDup.append(name)
        ageAlignName.append(age)
        LocAlignName.append(loc)
        nameSet.add(name)

print(NameNoDup)
print(ageAlignName)
print(LocAlignName)
```

**Output:**

```
['Jay', 'Boon', 'Sue', 'Tim', 'Lia', 'John', 'Abe']
[20, 40, 26, 28, 21, 91, 25]
['BA', 'CA', 'CO', 'AL', 'NY', 'NV', 'SO']
```